# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near why?

Tags: mariadb, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE table sign_up(
    firstname varchar(150),
    lastname varchar(150),
    birthdate date,
    tel int(8),
    cin int(8) PRIMARY,
    email varchar(150) PRIMARY,
    motdepass varchar(10) PRIMARY);
```

MariaDB said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '
> email varchar(150) PRIMARY,
> motdepass varchar(10) PRIMARY)' at line 6

Comment: What are all those "Primary" keywords doing there? Also suggest you store telephone numbers as a string, not a number (they are strings of digits, not a number).

Comment: `PRIMARY` should be `PRIMARY KEY` -- you can't abbreviate it.

Answer (score 2):

Correct syntax for multi-column primary key in mysql is like this:

```
CREATE table sign_up(
    firstname varchar(150),
    lastname varchar(150),
    birthdate date,
    tel int(8),
    cin int(8),
    email varchar(150),
    motdepass varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(cin, email, motdepass)
    )
    ;
```

On the other hand, if what you're looking for is to set `cin` as primary key, but want `email` and `motdepass` to be unique, then:

```
CREATE table sign_up(
    firstname varchar(150),
    lastname varchar(150),
    birthdate date,
    tel int(8),
    cin int(8) primary key,
    email varchar(150) unique,
    motdepass varchar(10) unique
    )
    ;
```

However, forcing `motdepass` (which is I guess where you store user passwords) to be `unique` may not be a great idea, since if a user with malicious intent tries to create an account in your application, and the app throws an error, then given that everything else is correct, the user will know that someone else already used the same password.

Comment: On the other hand OP may be looking for 1 PRIMARY and 2 UNIQUE keys

Comment: @P.Salmon could be, you're right. Edited my answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sign_up`(
    'firstname' varchar(150),
    'lastname' varchar(150),
    'birthdate' date,
    'tel' int(8),
    PRIMARY KEY 'cin' int(8) ,
    KEY 'email' varchar(150),
    KEY 'motdepass' varchar(10));
```

it cannot have more than one primary key.
you can check same issue
[Can a Microsoft SQL table have more than one Primary Key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106090/can-a-microsoft-sql-table-have-more-than-one-primary-key/3106094)

Comment: don't assume because microsoft sql table can't have more than 1 primary key that the same applies to mysql (it can't ,but that's not the point)